# I can not logoff

Tags: macos, login

I can't log out of my user account. I am running 10.10.3 (14D136) on a 2015 rMBP. FileVault is active. I get this console message

```
23.04.15 20:02:56,772 loginwindow[91]: ERROR | -[SessionLogoutManager startLogout:logoutSubType:showConfirmationUI:countDownTime:useTALOption:logoutOptions:] | Attempt to start a: Logout, AFTER a Shutdown was already past the point where logout can change types
```

The bigger problem is, I can only shutdown the system via the terminal.

Comment: Has another user initiated a shutdown command?    Does this behavior persist after you successfully shutdown via the terminal?

Comment: There is only one user. The problem persist after a reboot.

Answer (score -1):

This is apparently an item of concern on the Apple Support groups. Here is a process extracted from there:

1) Make a copy of your "home" folder and name it whatever you like.

2) Create a new user

3) Right-click on the new user account (in system preferences, where you created it) and choose "advanced options"

4) Change the default location of the home directory to the one you made a copy of in step 1

5) Right click on the copy of your Home account. Click on "Get info".

6) Click on the padlock (bottom right) and enter your administrator password

7) Click on the "+" button (bottom left) and select the name of your new user account from the pop-up that appears

8) Click on the settings button (bottom centre) and select "Apply to enclosed items"

9) Finally select your user account from the same settings button and select "Make {new user} owner" (or select 'Read & Write' in permissions in front of your new user account (This will allow your new user account access to all the same settings/documents as the original user)

10) Reboot and login to your new user account.

(You'll be asked to re-enter iCloud passwords).

THE NEXT STEP: you may need to correct some applications permissions from old user account that YOU (user) installed.

[The poster on AppleSupport](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6677744) had a convoluted method to change permissions. I suggest trying apps to see if any fail. If they do, they may have a permission/ownership problem as shown in the image.

You may have to set that in Terminal (you seem to know your way around there .)

Hope this helps

[image]

Comment: Doesn't a `chown` do the same?